# I habe ane error messege while installing Eclipse (Installation failed with an error)

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, error-handling, ide

> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Executing bootstrap tasks
>
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 15.0.2+7-27
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Product
> org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2021-03 [2021-05-10 08:37:17]
> Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.19.0.v20210223-0655, build=5032,
> branch=de1d74a6bf3addd102f8a873eabac293fbeaa3ad [2021-05-10 08:37:17]
> Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.19.0.v20210221-1019, build=5032,
> branch=de1d74a6bf3addd102f8a873eabac293fbeaa3ad [2021-05-10 08:37:17]
> Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.16.0.v20200814-1205, build=5032,
> branch=de1d74a6bf3addd102f8a873eabac293fbeaa3ad [2021-05-10 08:37:17]
> Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2021-03))
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Offline = false [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Mirrors =
> true [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Resolving 17 requirements from 3
> repositoriesto C:\Users\Deebo\eclipse\java-2021-032\eclipse
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.19.0,5.0.0) [2021-05-10
> 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
> [4.19.0,5.0.0) [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.19.0,5.0.0)
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group [2021-05-10
> 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [2021-05-10
> 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group [2021-05-10
> 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Requirement
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Repository
> http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-03/202103121200
> [2021-05-10 08:37:17] Repository
> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03/202103171000 [2021-05-10
> 08:37:17] Repository
> http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest [2021-05-10
> 08:37:20] Calculating requirements and dependencies. [2021-05-10
> 08:37:21] Computing prerequisite plan [2021-05-10 08:37:26] Collecting
> 1 artifacts from
> http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-03/202103121200
> [2021-05-10 08:37:26] Downloading
> epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64 [2021-05-10 08:37:26]
> Collected 1 artifacts for
> http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-03/202103121200
> in 0.008s [2021-05-10 08:37:26] Collecting 3 artifacts from
> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03/202103171000 [2021-05-10
> 08:37:26] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root [2021-05-10 08:37:26]
> Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root [2021-05-10 08:37:26] Downloading
> org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64 [2021-05-10
> 08:37:26] Collected 3 artifacts for
> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03/202103171000 in 0.5s
> [2021-05-10 08:37:28] An error was detected while performing the
> engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log
> for details. [2021-05-10 08:37:28] ERROR:
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.   at
> org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:551)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
> at
> org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
> ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context
> was:(profile=C__Users_Deebo_eclipse_java-2021-032_eclipse,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust,
> operand=, action=).   ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0
> Error reading signed content.   java.io.IOException: Exception in
> opening zip file:
> C:\Users\Deebo.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.5.800.v20200608-1251.jar
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:353)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
> C:\Users\Deebo.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.5.800.v20200608-1251.jar
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(Unknown
> Source)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:335)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
> at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
> ... 1 more
>
> [2021-05-10 08:37:28]

Answer (score 0):

If the installer program fails for you, you can always download zip package

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r

There's the installer link on top, but below that, there are links to zipped releases.

Download one of these, unzip it anywhere you want (for example into "C:\Eclipse"), and add shortcut to desktop manually.